# OCMock Partial Mock Object with Facade

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, ocmock

Note: I'm using OCMock 3.0.2 and Xcode 5.1.1.

I've got an object that operates as a Facade for another object it owns.  The way I structured it was to create a Protocol in the owned object for the methods I wanted exposed:

```
@protocol SyncEngineProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) updateAllGroups;

... more methods....

@end
@interface CoreDataSyncEngine : NSObject <SyncEngineProtocol>
@end
```

Then in the Facade, I create a category that conforms to this protocol, but I don't implement the category.  Instead, I forward those calls to the owned object:

```
@interface ModelManager (SyncMethods) <SyncEngineProtocol>
@end

@implementation ModelManager
...
- (id) forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector{
  if ([_syncEngine respondsToSelector:aSelector]){
    return _syncEngine;
  }
  return nil;
}
...
@end
```

I'm having two problems, and I don't know if they're related:

1. The main problem I'm having is when a Protocol method is called on the owning object (ModelManager), OCMock throws an unrecognized selector exception.
2. The second problem I'm having is every time I run my tests, I get several exceptions thrown in the OCMock framework when I attempt to create a class mock of the Sync Engine, which pauses the code execution.  I can continue through them and everything "seems" to work properly but obviously something is wrong.  This is a stack trace of the exception:

```
0   0x00000001020c2973 in objc_exception_throw ()
...
5   0x0000000102352ead in +[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:] ()
6   0x000000010dc128ac in +[NSObject(OCMAdditions) instanceMethodForwarderForSelector:] at /tmp/ocmock.13557/Source/Source/OCMock/NSObject+OCMAdditions.m:29
7   0x000000010dc11fbb in -[OCClassMockObject setupForwarderForClassMethodSelector:] at /tmp/ocmock.13557/Source/Source/OCMock/OCClassMockObject.m:110
8   0x000000010dc1292e in +[NSObject(OCMAdditions) enumerateMethodsInClass:usingBlock:] at /tmp/ocmock.13557/Source/Source/OCMock/NSObject+OCMAdditions.m:48
9   0x000000010dc11e63 in -[OCClassMockObject prepareClassForClassMethodMocking] at /tmp/ocmock.13557/Source/Source/OCMock/OCClassMockObject.m:97
10  0x000000010dc11b5b in -[OCClassMockObject initWithClass:] at /tmp/ocmock.13557/Source/Source/OCMock/OCClassMockObject.m:31
11  0x000000010dc1316f in +[OCMockObject mockForClass:] at /tmp/ocmock.13557/Source/Source/OCMock/OCMockObject.m:48
12  0x000000010dc13231 in +[OCMockObject niceMockForClass:] at /tmp/ocmock.13557/Source/Source/OCMock/OCMockObject.m:64
13  0x000000010dc06abb in +[CSGroupControllerTests setUp] at /Users/aaron/Dropbox/Client Projects/CrowdSporting/Codebase/crowdsportingTests/CSGroupControllerTests.m:56
14  0x000000010dee148b in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
15  0x000000010dee2a75 in -[XCTest run] ()
16  0x000000010dee14df in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
17  0x000000010dee2a75 in -[XCTest run] ()
18  0x000000010dee14df in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
19  0x000000010dee2a75 in -[XCTest run] ()
20  0x000000010dee41b4 in +[XCTestProbe runTests:] ()
...
27  0x0000000100b52e33 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

I don't think the two are related, but since I'm having the problems at the same time, I can't ignore the timing.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

I downgraded to OCMock 2.2.4 and all of the exceptions that were being thrown in the OCMock framework are no more, which kind of sucks because I much prefer the new Syntax in 3.0.

I still can't Mock the Facade though.  It seems that OCMock requires all methods be implemented... no dynamic forwarding.  I can do that, of course, but it's a pain.